# jQuery show hide content and Changing links

Tags: jquery

On some of my company page i want to use show and hide toggle details while click on links.

I used .toggle() but....

But here is minor issue , while User click on **Show more** content should slide down and more important this text 'Show more' should be change to "**Show less**" and this should be toggle. I hope you are clear what I really need.

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

John McCollum basically has your answer, but you could also make use of Javascript shorthand to make your code a little more compact:

```
$('#toggle').click(function(ev) { 
    $('#content').toggle(); 
    this.html(($('#toggle').text() == 'Show more') ? 'Show less' : 'Show more');
 })
```

EDIT: For clarity, I'll also add the `html` markup you need for the above code to work. In this example, everything is shown to start with.

```
<p><a id="toggle" href="#">Show less</a></p>
<div id="content"><!-- your stuff goes here. --></div>
```

If you want it to be hidden to start with, you simply change the link text to `"Show more"` and add the following style rule to your stylesheet:

```
#content { display: none; }
```

Comment: Fantastic solution. I found this after finding the following Snipplr code snippet which is a bit cleaner by making the above code a jQuery function you can call like so: element.toggleText('first value', 'second value');  

http://snipplr.com/view/8916/jquery-toggletext/

Comment: How would you do this with classes and have multiple divs with the same class trigger separately

Comment: @Carlos: If I needed this to be re-usable, I'd definitely write a jQuery plugin for it.

Comment: +1 Excellent idea.  However, the above syntax did not work for me.  Here is what what I used: `$(this).html(($('#toggle').text() == 'Show more') ? 'Show less' : 'Show more');`

Comment: @DavidHAust: I have always been a little confused on when to use `$.html()` and when to use `$.text()`, as I've had problems with both of them in different situations (mostly problems of the returning-nothing-at-all kind). I've updated my post to reflect your version - after all, that at least works for *one* person (mine was untested at the time of writing this post) =)

Comment: love that shorthand conditional statement. It's so tidy :)

Answer (score 4):

Create toggle functions to set the text of your link and animate your content div

```
$('a.toggle').toggle( 
    function() { 
        $('#contentDiv').slideDown(); 
        $(this).html('Show less');
    }, 
    function() { 
        $('#contentDiv').slideUp(); 
        $(this).html('Show more');
    } 
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it...

HTML:

```
    <a href="#" id="expand">
        <span class="linktext" >Show More</span>
        <span class="linktext" style="display:none">Show Less
        </span>
    </a>
    <div id="details" style="display:none"><h1>This is the details</h1></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('a#expand').click(function() {
        $('div#details').slideToggle();
        $('span.linktext').toggle();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the value  of a link with id 'toggle' by doing the following:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="toggle">Show More</a>
```

jQuery (within your toggle function):

```
$('a#toggle').text('Show less');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide and show elements with jquery [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) functions, there is also a [`slideDown`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) function.

so you would fire something like this onclick

```
$("#showMore").click(function(){
    $("#showMore").hide();
    $("#showLess").show();
    $("#contentDiv").slideDown();
}
```

that should just about do it, let me know if you have any other questions.